# How to open url in new tab from JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, html, url, target

I am developing a chatbot using peekabot (link provided below for documentation and official example), and want to be able to open a URL in a new tab (as you would have the option to do using plain html) when a user clicks on an option. Linked with this is the fact that the URL button that is generated is styled wrong (shows up as blank without the label text on mouse-hover-over).

I have included the whole script below for context, but the bit I am referring to is:

```
6: {
            text: 'You should check it out on test preview',
            options: [{
                text: "PREVIEW THIS LINK",
                url: "www.google.com"
            }]
        },
```

The above is option 6 and on clicking it the user should go to the URL (e.g. google.com) but open in a new tab and also not be blank (the button link is blank on hover over for some reason)

I have tried: url: "www.google.com" target="_blank (see below) but this breaks the whole javascript code.

```
6: {
                text: 'You should check it out on test preview',
                options: [{
                    text: "PREVIEW THIS LINK",
                    url: "www.google.com" target="_blank
                }]
            },
```

I have also tried:

```
url: "www.google.com target="_blank"
```

and

```
url: "www.google.com target=_blank"
```

neither works.

For an answer:

1. Solution for opening the URL in a new tab
2. Correction so that the button link (for the URL) is not BLANK on hover-over. (when you move the mouse away from the button link, the text appears)

This is the official site - https://peekobot.github.io/peekobot/  but irritatingly even in their example - the url to GitHub is opened in the same tab.

The whole script below for context:

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>js/bot.js>v=1"></script>

<script>
const chat = {
    1: {
        text: 'Some Text here',
        options: [{
            text: 'More Text here',
            next: 101
        },
     {
            text: '??',
            next: 201
        }
        ,
         {
            text: '?????',
            next: 301
        }   
    ]
    },
    101: {
        text: 'Some information here,
        options: [{
            text: 'That is great, thanks!',
            next: 102
        },
        {
            text: 'I would like some more info please.',
            next: 103
        }]
    },
    102: {
        text: 'Thanks and Goodbye',
        url: siteurl + "index.php/student/test",
        options: [{
            text: 'Bye and thank you.',
            next: 3
        },
        {
            text: 'I would like some more info please.',
            next: 104
        }]
    },
    103: {
        text: 'Info here',
        options: [{
            text: 'That is great, thanks!',
            next: 103
        },
        {
            text: 'I would like some more info please.',
            next: 104
        }]
    },
    5: {
        text: 'Aah, you\'re missing out!',
        next: 6
    },
    6: {
        text: 'You should check it out on test preview',
        options: [{
            text: "Go to PRIVIEW",
            url: "www.google.com"
        }]
    },
    
};


const bot = function () {

    const peekobot = document.getElementById('peekobot');
    const container = document.getElementById('peekobot-container');
    const inner = document.getElementById('peekobot-inner');
    let restartButton = null;

    const sleep = function (ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    };

    const scrollContainer = function () {
        inner.scrollTop = inner.scrollHeight;
    };

    const insertNewChatItem = function (elem) {
        //container.insertBefore(elem, peekobot);
        peekobot.appendChild(elem);
        scrollContainer();
        //debugger;
        elem.classList.add('activated');
    };

    const printResponse = async function (step) {
        const response = document.createElement('div');
        response.classList.add('chat-response');
        response.innerHTML = step.text;
        insertNewChatItem(response);

        await sleep(1500);

        if (step.options) {
            const choices = document.createElement('div');
            choices.classList.add('choices');
            step.options.forEach(function (option) {
                const button = document.createElement(option.url ? 'a' : 'button');
                button.classList.add('choice');
                button.innerHTML = option.text;
                if (option.url) {
                    button.href = option.url;
                } else {
                    button.dataset.next = option.next;
                }
                choices.appendChild(button);
            });
            insertNewChatItem(choices);
        } else if (step.next) {
            printResponse(chat[step.next]);
        }
    };

    const printChoice = function (choice) {
        const choiceElem = document.createElement('div');
        choiceElem.classList.add('chat-ask');
        choiceElem.innerHTML = choice.innerHTML;
        insertNewChatItem(choiceElem);
    };

    const disableAllChoices = function () {
        const choices = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
        choices.forEach(function (choice) {
            choice.disabled = 'disabled';
        });
        return;
    };

    const handleChoice = async function (e) {

        if (!e.target.classList.contains('choice') || 'A' === e.target.tagName) {
            // Target isn't a button, but could be a child of a button.
            var button = e.target.closest('#peekobot-container .choice');

            if (button !== null) {
                button.click();
            }

            return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        const choice = e.target;

        disableAllChoices();

        printChoice(choice);
        scrollContainer();

        await sleep(1500);

        if (choice.dataset.next) {
            printResponse(chat[choice.dataset.next]);
        }
        // Need to disable buttons here to prevent multiple choices
    };

    const handleRestart = function () {
        startConversation();
    }

    const startConversation = function () {
        printResponse(chat[1]);
    }

    const init = function () {
        container.addEventListener('click', handleChoice);

        restartButton = document.createElement('button');
        restartButton.innerText = "Restart";
        restartButton.classList.add('restart');
        restartButton.addEventListener('click', handleRestart);

        container.appendChild(restartButton);

        startConversation();
    };

    init();
}

bot();
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Based on a suggestion below, I've tried:

```
if (step.options) {
            const choices = document.createElement('div');
            choices.classList.add('choices');
            step.options.forEach(function (option) {
                const button = document.createElement(option.url ? 'a' : 'button');
                button.classList.add('choice');
                button.innerHTML = option.text;
                if (option.url) {
                    button.href = option.url;
            if (option.target) {
      button.target = option.target;
                } else {
                    button.dataset.next = option.next;
                }
                choices.appendChild(button);
            });
            insertNewChatItem(choices);
        } else if (step.next) {
            printResponse(chat[step.next]);
        }
    };
```

This breaks the whole code so the chatbot doesn't run at all.

Comment: did you try `url: "www.google.com target=_blank" ` ?

Comment: Thanks dmikester - I'll check question to update but yes - that was tried.It didn't break the code but the URL opened in the same tab, replacing the page.

Comment: Why is this voted down with no explanation?

Comment: I don't know how that addon/plugin works.  But I'm wondering if you can't do something like this: `options: [{
                    text: "PREVIEW THIS LINK",
                    url: "www.google.com",
                    target: "_blank"
}]`

Comment: could you put this in an answer in the context of my exact code so I can replicate/verify...like the end of the URL cuirently does not have }] ...

Comment: I tried what you suggested like so:  303: {
        text: ' - Not many people know this! Well done!',
     options: [{
            text: 'Quantum Computing Article',
            url: "https://www.wired.co.uk/article/quantum-computing-explained", target: "_blank"
        },
        {   which does not work.

Comment: Is there a site for documentation on that plugin somewhere?

Comment: This is the site - https://peekobot.github.io/peekobot/  but irritatingly even in their example - the url to GitHub is opened in the same tab. Thanks for your help dmikester1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm thinking is you would have to modify the code or get the author to modify the code for you.

I'm looking at the main js code here: https://github.com/Peekobot/peekobot/blob/master/peekobot.js

This snippet is what I am looking at:

```js
step.options.forEach(function (option) {
                const button = document.createElement(option.url ? 'a' : 'button');
                button.classList.add('choice');
                button.innerHTML = option.text;
                if (option.url) {
                    button.href = option.url;
                } else {
                    button.dataset.next = option.next;
                }
                choices.appendChild(button);
            });
```

That last part would get changed to something like this, I would think.

```js
if (option.url) {
   button.href = option.url;
   if (option.target) {
      button.target = option.target;
   }
} else {
...
```

Comment: For clarity, you are suggesting, just adding this bit: if (option.target) {
      button.target = option.target;

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately - and breaks the whole code.

Comment: I've posted an update with your suggested code in my question :)

Comment: you added that code to bot.js and it broke it?  Can you post your modified bot.js?

Comment: I've posted it above in my question. See update (at the end).

Comment: that is because you forgot to close your new `if`.  Look closely at the code, it is missing a `}`

Comment: AWESOME! Works. Could you help with the mouse-over bit....?!

Comment: Great, make sure to mark this as the answer.  Post a new question on SO and paste the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176954/text-disappears-on-javascript-generated-hyperlink-button-on-mouse-over Thanks so much!